# Time series prediction with LSTM using Keras: Wrong number of dimensions: expected 3, got 2 with shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, keras

I am trying to predict the next value in the time series using the previous 20 values. Here is a sample from my code:

`X_train.shape` is `(15015, 20)`

`Y_train.shape` is `(15015,)`

```
EMB_SIZE = 1
HIDDEN_RNN = 3

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_shape = (EMB_SIZE,), input_dim=EMB_SIZE, output_dim=HIDDEN_RNN, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(input_shape = (EMB_SIZE,), input_dim=EMB_SIZE, output_dim=HIDDEN_RNN, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, 
          Y_train, 
          nb_epoch=5, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=1, 
          validation_split=0.1)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=128)
print score
```

Though when I ran my code I got the following error:

`TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py:484"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 3, got 2 with shape (32, 20).')`

I was trying to replicate the results in this post: [neural networks for algorithmic trading](https://medium.com/@alexrachnog/neural-networks-for-algorithmic-trading-part-one-simple-time-series-forecasting-f992daa1045a#.muimc84k6). Here is a link to the git repo: [link](https://github.com/Rachnog/Deep-Trading)

It seems to be a conceptual error. Please post any sources where I can get a better understanding of LSTMS for time series prediction. Also please explain me how I fix this error, so that I can reproduce the results mentioned in the article mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your input data a set of 15015 1D sequences of length 20. According to Keras doc, the input is a 3D tensor with shape (nb_samples, timesteps, input_dim). In your case, the shape of `X` should then be `(15015, 20, 1)`.

Also, you just need to give `input_dim` to the first `LSTM` layer. `input_shape` is redundant and the second layer will infer its input shape automatically:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_dim=EMB_SIZE, output_dim=HIDDEN_RNN, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=HIDDEN_RNN, return_sequences=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

LSTM in Keras has an input tensor shape of `(nb_samples, timesteps, feature_dim)`

In your case, `X_train` should probably have an input shape of `(15015, 20, 1)`. Just reshape it accordingly and the model should run.